# var_dump array returning my string, double?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, session, authentication

After researching for hours, no proper fix has been found by myself so far, thus here I am!

I'm currently working on a school project that uses a login.php validator file to check if the user filled in all inputs, etc. etc., and also to create sessions.

```
require "config.inc.php";

    $query = ("SELECT username, password, active FROM *DATABASE* WHERE username='".$username."' AND password='".$password."' AND active='1'") or die(mysql_error());
    $result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query);
    $match  = mysqli_num_rows($result);

    if($match > 0){
       //Directing to account page
       header("Location:account.php");

       //User info search
       $queryID = ("SELECT id FROM *DATABASE* WHERE username='".$username."' AND password='".$password."' AND active='1'") or die(mysql_error());
       $resultID = mysqli_query($mysqli, $queryID);
       $id = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultID);

       $queryNAME = ("SELECT name FROM *DATABASE* WHERE username='".$username."' AND password='".$password."' AND active='1'") or die(mysql_error());
       $resultNAME = mysqli_query($mysqli, $queryNAME);
       $naam = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultNAME);

       //Session user info
       $_SESSION['id'] = $id;
       $_SESSION['naam'] = $naam;
```

This is just a minor piece of the validator, but as you can see it redirects to the account page (This works fine), and should create sessions for the name and ID found in the database.

The account page then again receives and translates the sessions to variables with the following code;

```
  //SESSIONS
  require 'session.php'; //CHECKS IF SESSION IS VALID, IF NOT: RETURN TO HOME

  //VARIABLES
  if (isset($_SESSION['naam']) && isset($_SESSION['id']) && isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
    print_r($_SESSION['naam']); //Debug purposes
    print_r($_SESSION['id']);
    print_r($_SESSION['username']);
    $id = implode($_SESSION['id']); //Convert to String
    $naam = implode($_SESSION['naam']);
    $username = ($_SESSION['username']); //Already a string, this was a variable used in the POST form
    var_dump($naam);
  } else {
    echo "No sessions"; //Debug purposes
  }
```

When I echo the username on my account page, it displays the username perfectly fine, and I assume that's because username has always been a string to begin with.

Yet when I echo the naam variable, it displays "AdministratorAdministrator" even though the naam in the database is just Administrator.

This is my print_r result:

```
Array ( [0] => Administrator [name] => Administrator )
Array ( [0] => 23 [id] => 23 ) 
admin
string(26) "AdministratorAdministrator"
```

Any clues on how I can ensure that whenever I echo the naam variable, it shows just Administrator ONCE, and not twice? thanks!

Comment: //header("Location:account.php");// You are redirecting before store values in session!!!, redirect should be at last line in your code. Also use exit; after redirect

Comment: whoa! How awkward is that, thanks so much :)

Comment: You also can't mix different mysql apis.

Comment: This is open to an SQL injection, use a prepared statement. Also, do not store plain text passwords, use `password_hash()`.

Comment: The output doesn't match the code - as you use `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` the result set should not have a numeric based index value - that should indicate that you used `mysqli_fetch_array()`.

Comment: Your `or die(mysql_error()` code is on setting a string value, usually they should be on the `mysqli_query()` call (if indeed at all) and as @FunkFortyNiner pointed out it should be `mysqli_error($mysqli)`.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, my password is in fact hashed with MD5, but I didn't include that part of the code in my question because I didn't consider it a requirement for this particular question. I'll check the or die() function again!

Comment: MD5 isn't safe at all and you stand at getting hacked. That hashing method is over 30 years old and has been broken.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to save onlye the data you need in the Session

```
$_SESSION['id'] = $id['id'];
$_SESSION['naam'] = $naam['name'];
```

In your case you are saving the entire result from the function `mysqli_fetch_assoc`, which is an array, as you can see from the docs:

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php